# PHP: Export DB Table to CSV FILE

Tags: php, csv, wordpress

I've got a custom table in WordPress and I'd like to be able to export the data in that table as a FILE in CSV (semi-colon seperated) format.

I've got the data coming out properly, but how do I then save it as an attachment?

Keep in mind that when using WordPress, headers have already been set... and I really don't know how to get around that.

Comment: do you mean you used a plugin that generates custom table, and you want to export a table that is generated by that plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly HOW you're doing what you're TRYING to do ...

... but this link gives you a simple, straightforward way to write the data as a .csv file you can do a "save as" from your browser:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/export-wordpress-db-table-to-excel

Answer (score 0):

For these plugins, they use database to store row & column details. You have to extract the data in MySQL database tables ( those table names are usually named after the plugin's name ) .

If you are still not sure how to do, you can just **copy** the table being displayed in page in browser, then **paste** in Excel. Last, save as CSV or XLS if you like.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code. just copy and past and you have it :)

https://gist.github.com/umairidrees/8952054#file-php-save-db-table-as-csv